# Method not counting number of times the string is used

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to count the number of times a word from a dictionary is used. This is my code:

```
def substrings(words, dictionary)
  hash = {}
  substrings.downcase!
  dictionary.each do |substring|
    words.each do |word|
      if word.include? substring +=1
      end
    end
  end
  hash.to_s
end

dictionary = ["below", "down", "go", "going", "horn", "how", "howdy", "it", "i", "low", "own", "part", "partner", "sit"]
substrings = "below", dictionary
```

This is the result:

```
["below", ["below", "down", "go", "going", "horn", "how", "howdy", "it", "i", "low", "own", "part", "partner", "sit"]]
```

But I'm looking for something like this:

```
=> {"below"=>1, "low"=>1}
```

Comment: You are not even calling your function.

Comment: `words.split.count { |w| dictionary.include? w }`

Comment: "I'm not getting the count" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases?

Comment: How do you determine that you are "not getting the count"? In the code snippet you posted, you never even call `substrings`, so how do you know that it isn't working correctly if you don't even call it? And what is a "count"? `substrings` returns the `String` representation of a `Hash`, but the word "count" implies a number of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

you are redefining the method, not calling it. replace the last line with

`substrings("below", dictionary)`